# How I can omit `React.Fragment` when I work with children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with simple structure of react elements:

```
...
<ComponentWrapper>
  <FirstComponent />
  <SecondComponent />
  <ThirdComponent />
</ComponentWrapper>
...
```

And in my `ComponentWrapper` I wanna work with all children, but in my `FirstComponent` I have such a structure:

```
const FirstComponent = () => {
  return <>
   <Subcomponent />  
   <Subcomponent />
   <Subcomponent />
  </>
```

So in this structure in `ComponentWrapper` I got only 3 child, but actually I have to get 5.
3 kids from `FirstComponent` and 2 kids from second and third component.

May somebody have an idea how to omit `React.Fragment` and got 3 child from first component?

Comment: How can you get `5` child, since you are passing only `3`. What exactly do you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

the [react-keyed-flatten-children](https://github.com/grrowl/react-keyed-flatten-children) package seems like it'd solve your problem while keeping `FirstComponent` as is.

```
import flattenChildren from 'react-keyed-flatten-children'

const ComponentWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {flattenChildren(children)}
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score -2):

You could add whatever components you want to render inside `Firstcomponent` to an array. and then return that array, like so

```
export default function FirstComponent () {
  const x = [];
  x.push(<p>Hello</p>);
  x.push(<p>Hello</p>);
  x.push(<Subcomponent/>);
  x.push(<Subcomponent/>);

  return x;
}
```

or instead of pushing them in an array and then returning the array, just directly return it like this

```
return [
    <p>Hello</p>,
    <p>Hello</p>,
    <Subcomponent/>,
    <Subcomponent/>
  ]
```

You might have to give each element a key prop too. Also please note it is always beeter to use react fragment.
The react docs have a section that mention this: [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children)

Comment: @yoshi React Docs mention it though: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#jsx-children It says "A React component can also return an array of elements"

Comment: @yoshi I did try a pretty simplistic example of this before posting, with react v16, v17 Seemed to worked for me even with functional components https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cdanbn?file=src/example.js

Comment: It seems I judged too quick, I'm sorry about that!  

Comment: Ohh its totally fine.